How to bind WPF TreeView's style item property IsExpanded to a command in MVVM
I have a WPF application that uses MVVM. There I have a treeview and need to add a button to collapse all nodes. The treeview has a custom ItemContainerStyle with the setter property IsExpanded. I want to bind it to the MVVM and button click command but don't know how (I have the button bound to RelayCommand). Alternatively, there may be another (better?) way to do it, but as there is already MVVM used, I don't want to implement it in the code-behind. Thanks for any advice.
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle2}">
</TreeView>

<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>


You would need to bind the TreeViewitem IsExpanded porperty to Node property, then when you execute button command, iterate through nodes and set property bound to IsExpanded to false. very easy.

Opinion: If you are doing things that only affect the GUI you should do it in the code behind and not in the ViewModel or else your ViewModel is no longer independant of the GUI. The ViewModel must not and shall not know whats happening with the data in the view, thats for the view to handle.

As XAMlMAX said, you can bind the TreeViewItem's IsExpanded property to a view model property by using ItemContainerStyle. Here's an example:
XAML
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:Person"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>

View Model
public class Person : ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }

    #region bool IsExpanded property
    private bool _IsExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_IsExpanded == value)
                return;
            _IsExpanded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public List<Person> People { get; } = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person
        {
            Name = "Larry",
            IsExpanded = true,
            Children = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person
                {
                    Name = "Curly",
                },
                new Person
                {
                    Name = "Moe",
                    IsExpanded = false,
                    Children = new List<Person>
                    {
                        new Person
                        {
                            Name = "Little Moe",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

Note that this is a smidge unsafe since this TreeViewItem style is now logically bound to the particular view model (whereas you generally want to try to limit those kinds of dependencies to the DataTemplate), and there's no type-checking XAML side. So just be cautious here.
Then for your collapse-all button just recursively iterate through the tree from top down to collapse all the members.
Finally there's a comment above suggesting that it's somehow inappropriate for a view model to control something like the expanded state of a tree view item and that anything that touches on a UI concept "must" be done in code behind instead. This is a bizarre misinterpretation of MVVM which became prevalent on SO a few years ago, which I've written extensively about. Some examples for those interested -
In MVVM is it acceptable to access the ViewModel in the view's code behind?
WPF MVVM Code Behind Best Practices
WPF MVVM calling ViewModel methods from code behind
Bottom line, this is a perfectly appropriate, if not common, function for a view model to control, and in fact is far preferable to using single-purpose .xaml.cs code-behind.
